# Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in .php file

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP and SQL, but I'm trying to create a login script for my webapp.
For some reason I'm stuck. When the username or password-field is empty, there is an alert, but when they are both filled in correct or incorrect, there is no alert.

When I open the website in my browser (Chrome) and inspect the page, I get:

**"POST ../App/auth.php 500 (Internal Server Error)"**

When I open the error.log-file from my server, I get:

**"PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function query() on a non-object in ../App/class.manageUsers.php on line 24, referer: ../App/login.php"**

line 24 in class.manageUsers.php is:

```
$query = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND
password = '$password' LIMIT 1");
```

class.manageUsers.php:

```
<?php

include_once('class.database.php');

class ManageUsers{

    protected $link;

    function __construct(){
        $db_conn = new ManageDatabase;
        $this->link = $db_conn->connect();
        return $this->link;
    }
    function addUsers($username,$firstname,$lastname,$email,$password,$user_level){
        $query = $this->link->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username,firstname,lastname,email,password,user_level)
            VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)
        ");
        $values = array($username,$firstname,$lastname,$email,$password,$user_level);
        $query->execute($values);
        $rowCount = $query->rowCount();
        return $rowCount;
    }
    function loginUsers($username,$password){
        $query = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password' LIMIT 1");
        $rowCount = $query->rowCount();
        return $rowCount;           
    }
    function listUsers($user_id = null){
        if(isset($user_id))
        {
        $query = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$user_id' LIMIT 1");
        }
        else
        {
        $query = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC");
        }
        $rowCount = $query->rowCount();
        if($rowCount >= 1)
        {
            $result = $query->fetchAll();
        }
        else
        {
            $result = 0;
        }
        return $result;
    }

    function editUsers($user_id,$param){
        foreach ($param as $key => $value)
        {
        $query = $this->link->query("UPDATE users SET $key = '$value' WHERE id = '$user_id' LIMIT 1");
        }
        $rowCount = $query->rowCount();
        return $rowCount;
    }

    function deleteUsers($user_id){
        $query = $this->link->query("DELETE FROM users WHERE id = '$user_id' LIMIT 1");
        $rowCount = $query->rowCount();
        return $rowCount;
    }

}

?>
```

class.database.php:

```
<?php

class ManageDatabase{

    protected $db_conn;
    protected $db_host = 'localhost';
    protected $db_name = 'jqueryMobile';
    protected $db_user = 'root';
    protected $db_pass = '';

    function connect(){
        try{
            $this->db_conn = new PDO("mySQL:host=$this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name",$this->db_user,$this->db_pass);
            return $this->db_conn;
        }
        catch(PDOexception $e){
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}
?>
```

I hope someone can find where it seems to go wrong. 
Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't look like you have PDO [error handling set to throw exceptions](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php), so it won't actually throw (even if it did, your method of handling that exception is quite strange). You should use bind variables in all the queries, not just inside `addUsers()`. (Also, you can't return things from a constructor.)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, direct reason for error is empty 'link' property. Looks like dbmanager class failed when connecting to db. That would explain why query method cannot be called.